# Sf/f novel with mother/daughter conflict and winter hibernation

Tags: story-identification

Looking for a SF/f novel (maybe YA, but not sure) about a conflict between young woman and her mother (the queen?). They live in a town surrounded by mountains that leave the town in shadow during the winters. Most people retire to their homes and sleep for the winter. A system of mirrors on the mountains reflect sunlight into the town, causing rapid thawing in the spring. Might have been published in the 80s or 90s.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The people are human?  But they can hibernate through the winter?  Do they eat a lot in the fall to store up energy?

Comment: @DavidW - That's my excuse for all that pizza

Comment: The people are human. I don’t recall anything about eating in the fall, but agree it would be a great excuse for pizza.

Comment: @Valorum I disagree.  Pizza doesn't need an excuse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure which one you're thinking of, but it's definitely one of the [Sunstone trilogy](https://www.goodreads.com/series/100006-sunstone-scrolls) by Sydney Van Scyoc. The people do eat a lot and hibernate; the royal family (mother is a "baronha") do not. The baronha goes up into the mountains during the winter and gathers sunlight in her sunstone bracelets; then comes back down in the spring and uses the power to thaw the snow. Baronhas only have daughters, who stay in the palace while their mother is away.https://www.fantasticfiction.com/v/sydney-j-van-scyoc/sunstone-scrolls/

Comment: https://sfmistressworks.wordpress.com/2018/02/14/darkchild-sydney-j-van-scyoc/ has a longer review.